# Split string in R，better to use regular expressions

Tags: r, split

I'd like to split a text string in R

for example:`"cell_70001.ERP123.138_D11_62.5Y_45880"`

But,I want `ERP123.138_D11_62.5Y_45880` finally.

That is to say, cut the place where the first punctuation starts, get the part after it,
I really don’t understand regular expressions, but I’m very anxious. I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your aim is to get where the first punctuation starts, considering `_` is a word, we could do:

```
sub(".*?\\W","", "cell_70001.ERP123.138_D11_62.5Y_45880")
[1] "ERP123.138_D11_62.5Y_45880"
```

This is to say, delete everything until the first non-word character.

You could also do it as:

```
sub("\\w+\\W","", "cell_70001.ERP123.138_D11_62.5Y_45880")
[1] "ERP123.138_D11_62.5Y_45880"
```

Which means delete every word until the first non-word. Which is then also deleted

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the code you written to me simply?The code works!But I don't konw why. Thank you again!